# How to set timezone for rails and sqlite?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rails-activerecord

The test app:

```
$ rails new ra1
$ cd ra1
$ ./bin/rails g model m1 dt1:datetime
$ ./bin/rake db:migrate
```

Then I add `config.time_zone = 'Europe/Kiev'` into `config/application.rb`, run console:

```
irb(main):001:0> M1.create dt1: Time.now
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "m1s" ("dt1", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["dt1", "2015-03-30 11:11:43.346991"], ["created_at", "2015-03-30 11:11:43.360987"], ["updated_at", "2015-03-30 11:11:43.360987"]]
   (33.0ms)  commit transaction
=> #<M1 id: 3, dt1: "2015-03-30 11:11:43", created_at: "2015-03-30 11:11:43", updated_at: "2015-03-30 11:11:43">
irb(main):002:0> Time.now
=> 2015-03-30 14:12:27 +0300
irb(main):003:0> Rails.configuration.time_zone
=> "Europe/Kiev"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Values in the database are always stored in UTC, no matter the `time_zone`.

The time zone configuration affects only the Ruby environment. The data is fetched from the database and the dates are converted into the selected timezone. The same applies to new time instances, as you noticed using `Time.now`.

The main reasons the time is normalized in the database is that it allows to easily convert the same value to multiple timezones, or change the timezone after the initial phase of the project without the need to reconvert all the dates. It's a good practice to use UTC in the database.

Comment: I thought if it says `#<M1 ... dt1: "2015-03-30 11:11:43" ...>`, that's what I get on `ruby`'s side. As it turns out `M1.first.dt1` returns proper value (`Mon, 30 Mar 2015 14:11:43 EEST +03:00`).